# Compose TextField clears value on gaining focus

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Composable function which displays 2 `TextField`s. Here's my code:

```
fun CreateEntryItem() {

    var wordA by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var wordB by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column {
        Row {
            TextField(
                value = wordA,
                onValueChange = { wordA = it },
                enabled = true,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            TextField(
                value = wordB,
                onValueChange = { wordB = it },
                enabled = true,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

When I give focus to TextField A, I can type and the value of `wordA` updates correctly.

Here's the weird behaviour:

I then give focus to TextField B. I then give focus back to TextField A. When I start typing, instead of TextField A inserting / appending characters at the cursor position in the existing text, it completely clears the existing text (as set pre-focus), and 'starts afresh'. That is to say, each TextField only remembers text entered in the current 'focus session'.

Am I doing this wrong? Or is this a bug in Compose? I reproduced this behaviour on both `1.0.0-beta07` and `1.0.0-beta08`.

Comment: Not able to reproduce on 1.0.0-beta08 need more details I guess

Comment: It's a big bug :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this isn't a Compose bug per se, but an emulator issue. Running the exact same code on a real device didn't run into this issue.

The emulator that encountered this issue was API 30 running on macOS Big Sur. I haven't tested whether other systems are also affected by this emulator bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My issue surfaced on custom Android device running Android 27.

I was able to trace the issue down into `IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage()`

When I first start typing characters, I receive `message.what = DO_SET_COMPOSING_TEXT`.

After regaining focus, the first message with a new character is `message.what = DO_COMMIT_TEXT`. I'm not sure why the message type changed.

If you look farther up the call stack to `RecordingInputConnection` you see that `DO_COMMIT_TEXT` fires off a `CommitTextCommand` which by design clears any text:

```
// API description says replace ongoing composition text if there. Then, if there is no
// composition text, insert text into cursor position or replace selection.
if (buffer.hasComposition()) {
  buffer.replace(buffer.compositionStart, buffer.compositionEnd, text)
} else {
  // In this editing buffer, insert into cursor or replace selection are equivalent.
  buffer.replace(buffer.selectionStart, buffer.selectionEnd, text)
}
```

Since I'm not able to debug the IME on this device, I replaced the Compose `TextField` with an `AndroidView` wrapping `android.view.TextView`. Not a great solution but it worked.